# Query for wc_get_products function to get products if attribute value in range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy

I have a product attribute with a slug `height`
I want to get all products where `height` is in a numeric range.
This queries doesn't works:

```
array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'paginate' => true,
  'limit' => $limit,
  'offset' => $offset,
  'attributes' => array(
                    array(
                      'field'   => 'slug',
                      'name'    => 'height',
                      'value'   => array( $min_value, $max_value ),
                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                      'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                  )
  );

array(
  'status' => 'publish',
  'paginate' => true,
  'limit' => $limit,
  'offset' => $offset,
  'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'taxonomy'=> 'pa_height',
                      'name'    => 'height',
                      'value'   => array( $min_value, $max_value ),
                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                      'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                  )
  );
```

Is there any way to query by attribute values range?

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Tax_Query` will only accept `'term_id'` or `'slug'` for the `fields` parameter

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @since 4.1.0 Added support for `$operator` 'NOT EXISTS' and 'EXISTS' values.
 *
 * @param array $tax_query {
 *     Array of taxonomy query clauses.
 *
 *     @type string $relation Optional. The MySQL keyword used to join
 *                            the clauses of the query. Accepts 'AND', or 'OR'. Default 'AND'.
 *     @type array {
 *         Optional. An array of first-order clause parameters, or another fully-formed tax query.
 *
 *         @type string           $taxonomy         Taxonomy being queried. Optional when field=term_taxonomy_id.
 *         @type string|int|array $terms            Term or terms to filter by.
 *         @type string           $field            Field to match $terms against. Accepts 'term_id', 'slug',
 *                                                 'name', or 'term_taxonomy_id'. Default: 'term_id'.
 *         @type string           $operator         MySQL operator to be used with $terms in the WHERE clause.
 *                                                  Accepts 'AND', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'EXISTS', 'NOT EXISTS'.
 *                                                  Default: 'IN'.
 *         @type bool             $include_children Optional. Whether to include child terms.
 *                                                  Requires a $taxonomy. Default: true.
 *     }
 * }
 */
```

You may need to get products that have this attribute and loop the result for the value between.